# Scan a document and convert to key text

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am trying to find a way to scan a "paper document" with my scanner and then, trying with a programming language, like C# or C++, to figure out what letters are printed on the page to convert them to normal text.

In other words, I am trying to implement a "key from scanned image" function in order to convert a paper document to an electronic document to be opened with something like Notepad. Can anyone give me some tips, please?

Comment: Are you planning on creating your own OCR framework?

Comment: mmm yes, if the isn't a library ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do is something like OCR, or Optical Character Recognition. It's certainly not a simple field of study, but this wiki page should get you started with the concepts and what it is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Comment: since You gave me a point to start, I will accept your answer as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create one application to scan your images and OCR them using a 3rd party toolkit similar to leadtools. For more information, see this [link](http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/36579/ShowPost.aspx):

Comment: Are you associated with this product?